# Handling touch events in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` and an `UIImageView` as its subview. I want to draw on the imageview in response to the single touches. And I want to zoom and pan the image view in the scroll view on pinch and pan gestures respectively. I found many solutions. But its not perfect. Please give me a straight forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

use after subclassing UIScrollview.See the [link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html).If you are doing application for iphone4 OS,try to use UIGestureRecogniser.see the sample code for it in Apple site.

Comment: The solution i previously found is that initially i will set the userinteraction enabled property of the scrollview to false. And add the pinch and pan gesture property to image view. As soon as the event triggers the userinteraction enabled property is set to true. So all the events will pass to the scrollview. But this is creating some lag.

Comment: i told to use UITabGestureRecogniser for finding out single tap to change image in UIScrollview...i think that is your need..

Comment: K. But my purpose is not changing image. it will draw on the image (using quartz 2d) view in response to the user touch events. so tap will not do good in this situation. i want to recognize a single user touch. And the respose have to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using the scrollview for panning and zooming, I would suggest subclassing UIImageView to provide that functionality yourself along with the drawing. This will allow you to have finer control over it and quicker code. A scrollview is not very good at allowing complex gestures within it. (other than taps)

Comment: can you give me a good solution for programatically scrolling image in a uiscrollview. One solution is scaling the image by scale factor. But it will increase the image size which will make issue of memory management.